# Finding words which start and end with a consonant

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find words which start and end with a consonant. Below is what I tried, and it is not what I am looking for. I am really stuck and need your help/suggestions.

```
import re

a = "Still, the conflicting reports only further served to worsen tensions in the Ukraine crisis, which has grown drastically \
in the past few weeks to a new confrontation between Russia and the West reminiscent of low points in the Cold War." 

b = re.findall(" ([b, c, d, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, p, q, r, s, t, v, w, x, y, z, ',', '.'].+?[b, c, d, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, p, q, r, s, t, v, w, x, y, z, ',', '.']) ", a.lower())
print(b)
```

Output is:

```
['the conflicting', 'further', 'to worsen', 'the ukraine crisis,', 'has', 'drastically', 'the past', 'weeks', 'new', 'between', 'the west', 'low', 'the cold']
```

But the output is not correct. I have to use regular expressions. Without it it would be too tough, I guess.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you want to include commas and periods?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very clear solution using [`startswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith). In order to achieve your goal, you have to strip special chars on your own and convert your string into a list of words (named `s` in the code):

```
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
[w for w in s if not w.lower().startswith(vowels) and not w.lower().endswith(vowels)]
```

Comment: how is this different from @warunsl's answer?

Comment: @MattDMo at least for me, it's more verbose to use `startswith/endswith`.

Comment: if `a` is an input string then you could find `s` (the word list) as `s = re.findall(r'\w+', a)` It is better than `s = a.split()` because it allows punctuation in the input.

Comment: `(not x and not y)` could be written as `not (x or y)` The latter might be easier to understand (less negations).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - thanks, I hadn't seen that earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
words = [w for w in a.split() if w[0] not in vowels and w[-1] not in vowels]
```

This however would not take care of words ending in `.` and `,`

EDIT: If you have to find patterns using regex:

```
ending_in_vowel = r'(\b\w+[AaEeIiOoUu]\b)?' #matches all words ending with a vowel
begin_in_vowel = r'(\b[AaEeIiOoUu]\w+\b)?' #matches all words beginning with a vowel
```

We then need to find all words which either don't begin in a vowel nor end in a vowel

```
ignore = [b for b in re.findall(begin_in_vowel, a) if b]
ignore.extend([b for b in re.findall(ending_in_vowel, a) if b])
```

And your result is then:

```
result = [word for word in a.split() if word not in ignore]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a good solution. Is there any way that I can do this WITH regular expressions?

Comment: @FriendlyUser - sure. Split your sentence on spaces, and strip off punctuation marks to make a list of lines. Use regex to match the first character of the word, and compare it to a list of consonants (or negatively to vowels, which is easier to type). Do the same with the last character. If both are true, save the word to a new list.

Comment: Regular expression? try `re.findall(r"\b[^aeiouAEIOU,.\s][^\s]*?[^aeiouAEIOU,.\s]\b", a)` but this may not work on all punctuation like hyphenated words.

Comment: @FriendlyUser Updated with regex solution.

Answer (score 1):

First you should `split()` `a`, so that you get each word. Then you check if the first letter and the last letter are in the list `consonants`. If it is, you `append` it to `all`, and at the end, you print the contents of `all`.

```
consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

a = "Still, the conflicting reports only further served to worsen tensions in the Ukraine crisis, which has grown drastically \
in the past few weeks to a new confrontation between Russia and the West reminiscent of low points in the Cold War."

all = []

for word in a.split():
    if word[0] in consonants and word[len(word)-1] in consonants:
        all.append(word)

print all
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were looking to remove punctuation, this regular expression will work:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b[bcdfghj-np-tv-z][a-z]*[bcdfghj-np-tv-z]\b', a.lower())
['still', 'conflicting', 'reports', 'further', 'served', 'worsen', 'tensions', 'crisis', 'which', 'has', 'grown', 'drastically', 'past', 'few', 'weeks', 'new', 'confrontation', 'between', 'west', 'reminiscent', 'low', 'points', 'cold', 'war']
```

However, your original attempt looked like it was trying to preserve commas and periods, so if that was your goal you could use this instead:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b[bcdfghj-np-tv-z][a-z]*[bcdfghj-np-tv-z][,.]?(?![a-z])', a.lower())
['still,', 'conflicting', 'reports', 'further', 'served', 'worsen', 'tensions', 'crisis,', 'which', 'has', 'grown', 'drastically', 'past', 'few', 'weeks', 'new', 'confrontation', 'between', 'west', 'reminiscent', 'low', 'points', 'cold', 'war.']
```

I'm not sure why `\b` in my first example wouldn't normally match the trailing punctuation (the docs says it will) but at any rate these work.

If you want to account for contractions, the expression would simply be this instead:

```
r"\b[bcdfghj-np-tv-z][a-z']*[bcdfghj-np-tv-z][,.]?(?![a-z])"
```